# MYSQL - Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tenho que fazer uma trigger, onde ao ser excluido um funcionário também será excluido seu dependente. Mas não consigo excluir. o código ficou assim:

```
delimiter $

create trigger TRG_excluiDependente_AD
after delete 
on Funcionario
for each row
begin
    -- alter table Dependente drop foreign key ID_Func;
    delete from Dependente where Dependente.ID_Func = old.ID_Func;
end$    

delimiter ;

drop trigger TRG_excluiDependente_AD;
alter table Dependente DROP foreign key  fk_dep_func ;
delete from Funcionario where ID_Func = 4;
```

E me retorna o erro do título,e eu ja removi a FK funcinario->Dependente

Comment: na table de dependente faz referencia ao funcionario? se sim so coloca um "delete on cascade" que resolve seu problema

Comment: sim, mas o negócio é que não posso usar cascade

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVI

delimiter $

create trigger TRG_excluiDependenteAntes_BD -- -> BD Before delete (Antes)
before delete 
on Funcionario
for each row
begin

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
delete from Dependente where Dependente.ID_Func = old.ID_Func;
```

end$

delimiter ;

drop trigger TRG_excluiDependenteAntes_BD;
delete from Funcionario where ID_Func = 1;

---

delimiter $

create trigger TRG_excluiDependente_AD -- -> AD After delete (depois de deletar)
after delete 
on Funcionario
for each row
begin

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

end$

delimiter ;

Usando esta função que "cancela" temporariamente as chaves estrangeiras

Answer (score -3):

O dependente precisaria ter um registro de vinculo com uma *Foreign Key* (FK). Essa FK deveria ser do tipo `CASCADE`. Assim, quando excluir o funcionário, vai excluir o dependente.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).